# How to find all the columns of a particular index in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX on a table which has 3 columns. What would be an efficient way to get the columns on providing this index name?

Answer (score 1):

The following example returns all indexes and index columns for the table `myTbl`.

```
SELECT i.name AS index_name  
       ,COL_NAME(ic.object_id,ic.column_id) AS column_name  
       ,ic.index_column_id  
       ,ic.key_ordinal  
       ,ic.is_included_column  
FROM sys.indexes AS i  
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic   
       ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND i.index_id = ic.index_id  
WHERE i.object_id = OBJECT_ID('myTbl');
```

[Source here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-index-columns-transact-sql)

Comment: You should link your source... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-index-columns-transact-sql

Comment: @scsimon Thanks for the highlight. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can go to the Index folder in SSMS under that DB > Table and script out the Index to see everything about it. Or just right click on the index and click Properties, and the columns will be listed under `General`